# How to create a method that will work automatically once a day

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I have a project that get daily securities end of day values from the web and store them in a database.

I want it to happen once a day at a specific hour.

What is the best approach for that kind of need?

Comment: Windows Service or a Scheduled Task

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way:

Create a console app to perform the task and use the [Windows task scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Scheduler) to run it at the desired time and interval.

You could also create a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) but these are harder to deploy and debug than a console app.

Answer (score 1):

Option1: You can do it in your Csharp code using the date time check inside a timer control that triggers on regular interval. This approach is bad since it requires your application running continuously.

Option2: You can use a scheduled task in your OS and run the application at the specific hour to attain the same. My company follows this to generate automatic reports

Option3: You can use a windows service.([A Simple window service tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/simplewindowsservice.aspx))

Here is a [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6190/windows-service-or-windows-task-scheduler) that will help you decide whether to choose a scheduled task or a windows service.

Answer (score 1):

(easiest first)

1. Schedule your application using Windows Scheduler
2. Implement a Windows Service and use Quartz .NET for scheduling
3. Implement scheduling manually and just keep your application running forever

Answer (score 1):

You have a LOT of options, all with pros and cons. Just to name a few :

- A loop that would keep your application running in the background.
- A schedule agent that would launch your application once a day.
- Using Windows Scheduler.
- Another third party (or your own) scheduling application.

Given so little information, anything I'd be telling you about which is best for you wouldn't be worth a byte!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Midnight_Timer.aspx and change it from midnight to the time you require.